# Await doesn't work if async is not defined in Audio Query package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-audio-query

So I wanted to use audio query to list out the songs in flutter,
According to their documentation

```
List<SongInfo> songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
```

is the way to do the job,

But await can't work without async being defined. Can any solve this?

Comment: `await` can be called only in `async` method, more: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#why-asynchronous-code-matters

Comment: You could use `Future`'s `then` syntax. `audioQuery.getSongs().then(...)` However, I suspect that the reason you don't want to use await indicates that you are trying to use this API in the wrong place.

Comment: @RichardHeap Actually the above syntax is given in the documentation of the audioquery package. Actually asynchronous programming is necessary for it search the songs from my device. So how can I put async keyword when List<SongInfo> songs = await audioQuery.getSongs(); is the only statement required to list the songs. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: *"So how can I put async keyword when ..."* see https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: @Tushar I think you question by explaining why you can't use the statement as it is